# Is $(\mathbb{Z}_{n},+_{n},._{n})$ a field, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Is $(\mathbb{Z},+_{n},._{n})$ a field, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$?

My answer is No, because for $n=6$, $(\mathbb{Z}_{6},+_{6},._{6})$ has a zero divisor but a field has no zero divisors so it can't be a field.

Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, provided that you know a field contains no zero divisors.

Comment: Yes, and a more interesting result is that it *is* a field if and only if $n$ is prime.

Comment: Already we have a problem with $n=1$, since by definition a field has at least two elements.

Comment: @T.Bongers, oh, ok interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct; in fact, you can find counterexamples in a similar manner for any composite number $n$, since any non-trivial factor of $n$ is a zero divisor (and, in particular, non-invertible).

As a good exercise, one can generalize this statement to prove that the object in question is a field if and only if $n$ is prime.